# How to read values from dictionary value collection and make it comma seperated string?

Tags: c#-4.0, dictionary

I have a dictionary object as under

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictStr = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
dictStr.Add("Culture", new List<string>() { "en-US", "fr-FR" });
dictStr.Add("Affiliate", new List<string>() { "0", "1" });
dictStr.Add("EmailAddress", new List<string>() { "sreetest@test.com", "somemail@test.com" });
```

And I have an entity as under

```
public class NewContextElements
{ 
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

What I need to do is that for every value in a particular index of the dictionary value collection, I have to make a comma separated string and place it into List collection.

e.g. the NewContextElements collection will have (obviously at run time)

```
var res = new List<NewContextElements>();
res.Add(new NewContextElements { Value = "en-US" + "," + "0" + "," + "sreetest@test.com" });
res.Add(new NewContextElements { Value = "fr-FR" + "," + "1" + "," + "somemail@test.com" });
```

I was trying as

```
var len = dictStr.Values.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    var x =dictStr.Values[i];
}
```

no it is of-course not correct.

Help needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, len).Select( i =>
    new NewContextElements {
        Value = string.Join(",", dictStr.Values.Select(list => list[i]))
    }
);
```

`len` is the number of items inside the individual lists (in your example, it's two).

Comment: But how to add this into var res = new List<NewContextElements>();
?

Comment: I tried as Enumerable.Range(0, dictStr.Values.Count)
                 .ToList()
                 .ForEach(i => res.Add(new NewContextElements { Value = string.Join(",", dictStr.Values.Select(list => list[i])) })); but getting error as Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: @user1323981 `dictStr.Values.Count` is *not* the right number. You need to provide the number of items in the inner lists - something like `dictStr.Values.First().Count`.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean transform your data like

```
1 2 
3 4
5 6
```

to

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

try this block of code?  it can be optimized in a few ways.

```
var res = new List<NewContextElements>();
int i = dictStr.values.count()
for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {

    NewContextElements newContextElements = new NewContextElements();

    foreach (List<string> list in dictStr) {

        if (newContextElements.value() == null ) {

            newContextElements.value = list[i];

        } else  {

            newContextElements.value += ", " + list[i] );
        }      
    }
    res.add(newContextElements);
}
```

let me know if there are problems in the code, most like there is when you write it without a real ide.

Comment: A little change in original program for (int i=0; i < len; i++) 
            {

                NewContextElements newContextElements = new NewContextElements();

                foreach (List<string> list in dictStr.Values) 
                {

                    if (newContextElements.Value == null ) {

                        newContextElements.Value = list[i];

                    } else  {

                        newContextElements.Value += ", " + list[i];
                    }      
                }
                res.Add(newContextElements);
            } Error: Index out of range

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a slick as @dasblinkenlight's solution, but it should work:

```
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictStr = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>( );
        dictStr.Add( "Culture", new List<string>( ) {"en-US", "fr-FR"} );
        dictStr.Add( "Affiliate", new List<string>( ) {"0", "1"} );
        dictStr.Add( "EmailAddress", new List<string>( ) {"sreetest@test.com", "somemail@test.com"} );

        int maxValues = dictStr.Values.Select(l => l.Count).Max(); 
        List<NewContextElements> resultValues = new List<NewContextElements>(dictStr.Keys.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxValues; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string spacer = string.Empty;
            dictStr.Keys.ForEach( k => {
                                    sb.AppendFormat( "{0}{1}", spacer, dictStr[k][i] );
                                    spacer = ", ";
                                  } );
            resultValues.Add( new NewContextElements(  ){ Value = sb.ToString() });
        }
```